# Ng-bootstrap Import Error Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, ng-bootstrap

I try to run ng-bootstrap for angular 2 and I receive an error to install ng-bootstrap. I believe that is a path problem.
This 404 error occur when i try to access page, and on start npm.
When angular ng-bootstrap try to load I receive a 404 error on import module:

```
[1] 16.08.20 20:01:00 404 GET /@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

But this module is inside node_modules. Thanks

Comment: You can have look at the systemjs.config.js file at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html.

Comment: I try to solve and 404 errors has dismissed but the page does not load, stay in loading.

Comment: Can you show exactly the errors by using console tab in the browser?

Answer (score 8):

First you should install using below command

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Refer
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264181/angular2-ng-bootstrap-example) link, it has app module and system config reference and what he did wrong

in your app.module.ts

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
and
imports:      [ NgbModule]
```

in systemjs.config.js

```
**var map:** '@ng-bootstrap':          'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap'

**var packages:** '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap':       { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/634), it provides a good insight on how to configure ngBootstrap with systemJS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved with a few changes to the `systemjs.config.js`
[Getting started Angular2 RC5 with ng-bootstrap 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079892/getting-started-angular2-rc5-with-ng-bootstrap-404-error)

Answer (score 0):

check out my learning angular 2 project, I have just make some demos with angular 2 and ng-bootstrap. https://github.com/beginor/learning-angular2