# Angular2 + ng-bootstrap Example

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I started to learn Angular2 and I want to use ng-bootstrap in my project. However, I could not make a working project. It fails on importing ng-bootstrap. Since I am a beginner, I don't know if the problem is because of the code or something other that I made wrong.

Can you provide me a working **and simple** project with ng-bootstrap and Angular2 so I can try to make it work on my computer?

Edit:

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NgbdAlertCloseable } from './ngbd-alert-closeable.component';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ NgbModule, BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ NgbdAlertCloseable, AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@ng-bootstrap':          'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng-bootstrap':       { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  var ngBootstrapPackageNames = [
    'accordion',
    'alert',
    'bundles',
    'buttons',
    'carousel',
    'collapse',
    'dropdown',
    'esm',
    'modal',
    'pagination',
    'popover',
    'progressbar',
    'rating',
    'tabset',
    'timepicker',
    'tooltip',
    'typeahead',
    'util'
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  function ngBootstrapPackIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/' + pkgName] = {main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js'};
  }
ngBootstrapPackageNames.forEach(ngBootstrapPackIndex);
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: You says it fails on importing ng-bootstarp, how exactly did you do to import it and what's the error message ?

Comment: I edited the question. I added the app.module.ts file and the error message. It gives the error when I add NgbModule to 'imports'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I changed the

```
'ng-bootstrap':       { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

line in systemjs.config.js as

```
'@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap':         { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

And it worked!

Comment: I can't find systemjs.config.js file

Comment: There won't be a systemjs.config.js file if you're using angular-cli. Also, I don't know if it's still used in newer versions of Angular.